# Неправильно работает IF в Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Внизу в коде если проверяю с помошю dump или  dd все нормально работает, находит и удаляет фото из Database  и storage a . Но как только закрываю dump или dd код не рабоает. Так как я новичок не магу разобратся. Буду блогадарен любому помощи
 вот код:

```
 $item = Announcement::findOrFail($id);

        $item = $item->update([
            'title' => $this->getFormTranslations('title',$request),
            'content' => $this->getFormTranslations('content',$request),
            'category_id' => $request->category_id,
            'brand_id' => $request->brand_id,
            'model_id' => $request->model_id,
            'type_id' => $request->type_id,
            'region_id' => $request->region_id,
            'premium' => $request->premium,
            'status' => $request->status,
            'price' => $request->price,
            'name' => $request->name,
            'email' => $request->email,
            'phone' => $request->phone,
            'img' => $this->editImageFit($request->image,$item->img,$request->old_img,'announcements',$this->__thumbs)
        ]);

        $item = Photo::with('announcements')->where('announcement_id',$id)->get();          
        if($item){
            //dump(1111111111111111111);
         if($request->has('image')&& $request->old_img){
         $n = pathinfo($request->old_img, PATHINFO_FILENAME);
         $var2 = substr(strrchr($n, "_"), 0);
         $var2 = str_replace($var2,'',$n);
         //dump($n);
            //dump($var2);
           foreach($item as $val){
               //dump($val);
             $var = $val->img;  
             $n = pathinfo($var, PATHINFO_FILENAME);
             $e = pathinfo($var, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
              if($var2==$n){
                  $var2.='.'.$e;
                  $n.='.'.$e;
                    //dump($var2);
                    //dd($n);                 
                File::delete(base_path("storage/app/public/photos/".$n));
                $val->delete();
                }         
             }
           }
        }
            if($request->has('image')){
            $photos = Photo::create([
            'img' => $this->uploadImage($request->image,"photos"),
            'announcement_id' => $id,
            'user_id' => auth()->user()->id
            ]);
            }


        return redirect('/admin/announcements')->->with('message','ok');
    }
```